# How to run bash with root rights in C program?

Tags: posix

I have to write program in C that run bash with root rights.
I try to do this with exec but i dont how to login. Is this a good idea?

```
int main() {
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "bash";
    name[1] = NULL;
    execvp("/bin/bash", name);
}
```

Comment: (1) What did you expect this program to do, and what did it do instead?  Be detailed.  (2) If you think you have to use a setuid program to do X, *very probably* X is a bad idea, for any value of X.  Why do you need to do this?  (3) If you don't know what the word "setuid" means or why I brought it up, you need more help than we can give you.

Comment: Changed the tag from C to POSIX. has nothing to do with C, you could write that with any of the major programming languages, but all with the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executable needs to be setuid-root for this to work.

```
sudo chown root:root myprog 
sudo chmod 4755 myprog
```

Even if you do this, the shell might not give you root privileges if only the effective user ID is root.  You'll need to set the real user ID as well:

```
int main() {
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "bash";
    name[1] = NULL;
    setuid(0);      // sets the real user ID to 0 i.e. root
    execvp("/bin/bash", name);
}
```